# yum + connection refused

Tags: linux, port, curl, yum

I can install the ntp rpm as the following by yum 
but before yum installation I get the failed lines as the following:

```
 yum install ntp
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
http://linux02.sys65dns.com/DIR/centos7/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed connect to linux02.sys65dns.com:80; Connection refused"
Trying other mirror.
http://linux02.sys65dns.com/DIR/centos7/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed connect to linux02.sys65dns.com:80; Connection refused"
Trying other mirror.
http://linux02.sys65dns.com/DIR/centos7/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed connect to linux02.sys65dns.com:80; Connection refused"
Trying other mirror.
http://linux02.sys65dns.com/DIR/centos7/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed connect to linux02.sys65dns.com:80; Connection refused"
Trying other mirror.
http://linux02.sys65dns.com/DIR/centos7/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed connect to linux02.sys65dns.com:80; Connection refused"
Trying other mirror.
http://linux02.sys65dns.com/DIR/centos7/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed connect to linux02.sys65dns.com:80; Connection refused"
Trying other mirror.
http://linux02.sys65dns.com/DIR/centos7/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#7 - "Failed connect to linux02.sys65dns.com:80; Connection refused"
```

what this happens ?

Comment: similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132251/why-is-yum-trying-to-go-through-a-proxy-and-other-strange-behaviors

Answer (score 0):

the domain linux.sys65dns.com isn't valid. if this if from a mirrorlist, try a `yum clean all` and try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting steps (assuming this is your locally hosted repo):

1. Rומ `yum clean all` and try to install ntp again. For testing purposeד try to install a different package.
2. If the above fails, try to ping your server: ping linux02.sys65dns.com
3. If the above, try to open this in a web browser to check if port 80 is working fine or you can telnet as well.
4. If not, check the apache service on your server and if port 80 is open. You can also check the ports.conf to see if apache is configured to work on port 80 or a different port.